# Seeing through but not inside a cube

Tags: animation, materials, transparency

I want to be able to see through a cube, but not what is inside it. I would use this for text that seems to be being created from nowhere, but it is actually coming out of the bottom of the cube. 1: is this possible? 2:is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Blender Internal?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Cycles and there is nothing else in the Background you could try a Holdout-Shader. Transparency must be enabled of course. A backround image could then be composited in.
[image]

[image]